# Language and Complement language generated by the following Context free grammar?

Tags: context-free-grammar

```
G={ {S,A} , {a} , {S -> SAS | a , A -> aS | a} ,S}
```

In the answer section , its written:

> `L(G) = {a, a3, a4, a6, a7}`
>   and

Complement of L(G) is written as :  `{a2, a5, a8, ...}`.

Please help me understand how is the above language and its complement generated?

My try/analysis:

String for the above grammar should be minimum of 3 a's (No?) as: `S-> SAS` , substitute `S --> a` and `A --> a` in it we get , `S --> aaa`. But the solution `L(G)` starts with `a`.

Please help me understand this concept or am I interpreting something wrong.

Also, PLEASE explain is there any standard approach to figure out the Language from any Grammar? I googled a lot but couldn't find a general procedure. 
Thanks in advance.
PS-I'm preparing for a coming competitive exam.

Comment: 1 hour no reply :(? I think it should be some basic concept. Still waiting for some answer, please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For following grammar G:

```
G = {{S, A}, {a}, {S -> SAS | a, A -> aS | a}, S}
```

The language:

> `L(G) = {a, a3, a4, a6, a7}` is **not** correct.

String a<sup>5</sup> is also possible.

`a` is possible because there is a production `S --> a`,

`S`-productions are

```
S --> SAS 
S --> a
```

And `A`-productions are

```
A --> a
A --> aS
```

Every string in L(G) generates from `S`. To convert any sentential form into sentence you have to apply either `A --> a` or `S --> a` that is (odd length 1).

**The conman approach to figure out the Language from any Grammar** is "Generate Tree in sequence". :

To generate strings `w` grater than one length `|w| > 1`, your have to use production rule `S --> SAS`.

```
    T1:            T2:

     s             S
    /|\           /|\
   / | \         / | \  
  S  A  S       S  A  S 
  |  |  |      /  / \  \
  a  a  a     a  |   |  a
                 a   a
```

Next smallest possible string after a<sup>4</sup> is a<sup>5</sup> only:

```
    T3:  

     s             
    /|\           
   / | \         
  S  A   s       
 /  / \  |\
a  |   | a \
   a   a    a
```

So a<sup>5</sup> can't be in `L(G)`'s compliment language.

**EDIT:**

Idea for a<sup>8</sup>:

```
     T4:          

     s             
    /|\           
   / | \         
  S  A   S       
 /  / \   \
a  |   |   \
   a   a    T2
```

three `a`'s + five `a`s from T2 = eight `a`s

**Language of Grammar:**

> `L(G)` = is { `an` | where `n != 2` }

*Complement* of `L(G)` is `{aa}` only!

Comment: Thanks for the answer finally. I got the method for this particular grammar, will see if I'm able to find languages for other grammar.

Comment: So , what will be the right compliment language for the above language. If you say a^5 cant be in L(G)'s compliment language since its present in the language itself so shall I take that means-Complement language will contain all the strings not generated by the original language? If so , this means L(G)'s compliment will be {null,a^2, a^8)) ; a^8 because I'm not able to generate 8 a's from the grammar.
Please suggest.

Comment: @down-voter Your downvote really doesn't make me to delete  this **correct** answer and stop answering..

Comment: @BriteRoy Mind you make my answer up, someone downvoted in revenge (I don't know How is that? and Why?).